# Waiting from a desktop app for events originating from a metro app and vice versa

Tags: testing, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

We have a metro app and we want to test certain issues that may come up in the app due to multiple operations going on in async.
So basically our plan is to have a test app (preferably a desktop app) which can wait on certain events generated from within the metro app.We also want this to be bidirectional that is our desktop test app also generates certain events on which the metro app will wait (We will inject that part in the metro app code).This way we hope to generate more scenarios.
The problem is apparently in normal scenario events generated within metro app are not visible to other apps outside the app container.So is there a way to enable the eventing by some edits in the manifest file.
PS: We need this framework only for testing so currently we are not bothered about being flagged as the code won't be shipped with the IPC framework. As long as we are able to wait on events across processes it is fine. (Though we aim something that causes minimum interference with the original working of the app code)

EDIT:Also if we don't use eventing can we use RPC or any other form of communication that enables us to wait.

Comment: A quick google search seems to indicate that there are no supported mechanisms for IPC between Metro and desktop apps.

Comment: yes that's why this question is on stackoverflow. I need workarounds if any

Answer (score 0):

This is explicitly disabled.  The only way to sync would be through the cloud (a back end service) or through the file system.

Comment: that sounds like an overkill...:(